# Dijkstra not visiting all vertexes

Tags: c++, oop

i'm trying to implement Dijkstra minimal path with C++ and objects.

So far i think i got almost all the logic going except that my algorithm is exiting early I.E not visiting every node.

i think the issue is either with the way i populate my visited array or how i populate my Queue.

i'll join the code and basic input file.
you should be able to launch it by passing the input file name as an arg.

by advance, many thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100001
class Node
{
public:
  Node() {} /* An empty constructor */

  /* Store the information of an out-going edge from this node. */
  void add_successor( uint64_t const& node, int const& weight )
  {
    /* Manually check if this edge already exists. */
    for ( auto& p : successors )
    {
      if ( p.first == node )
      {
        /* If so, update its weight. */
        p.second = weight;
        return;
      }
    }
    /* If not, insert a new edge. */
    successors.emplace_back( make_pair( node, weight ) );
  }


  vector<pair<uint64_t, int>> getSuccessors(){
    return successors;
  }

  pair <uint64_t, int> getSuccessorWithMinDistance()
  {
    int minV = 999999; // minimal dist
    pair<uint64_t, int> minN;         // successor with minimal dist
    for (auto i = 0u; i < successors.size(); ++i)
    {
      if (successors.at(i).second <= minV)
      {
        minV = successors.at(i).second;
        minN = successors.at(i);
      }
    }
    return minN;
  }

private:
  /* List of the successors of this node. Can also be interpreted as the list of out-going edges.
     The first element of the pair is the successor node index, and the second element is the edge weight.
   */
  vector<pair<uint64_t, int>> successors;
};

class Graph
{
public:
  /* The constructor fills the vector `nodes` with `n` elements. */
  Graph( uint32_t const n )
    : nodes( n )
  {}

  void add_edge( uint64_t const from, uint64_t const to, int const weight )
  {
    if ( from == to )
    {
      return;
    }
    nodes.at( from ).add_successor( to, weight );
  }

  vector<uint64_t> dijkstra_shortest_path( uint64_t const from, uint64_t const to )
  {
    if ( from == to )
    {
      return vector<uint64_t>( 1, from ); /* Returns a vector of a single element, which is `from`. */
    }
    vector<uint64_t> minDist(nodes.size(),99999999); // Dist matrix that will store distances
    minDist[from] = 0; // 
    queue<Node> Queue; //  
    Queue.push(nodes.at(from)); // source is pushed first
    bool Visited[MAX];
    while (Queue.size() != 0)
    {

      Node Curr = Queue.front(); // node we're looking from
      Queue.pop();
      pair<uint64_t, int> Next = Curr.getSuccessorWithMinDistance(); // node we'll go to
      Node NextNode = nodes.at(Next.first);
      vector<pair<uint64_t, int>> neighbours = NextNode.getSuccessors();
      for (auto neighbour : neighbours) 
      // Curr neighbors
      // if(std::find(Visited.begin(), Visited.end(), neighbour.first) != Visited.end()){
      // }
      // else
      {
        int neighbourW = int(neighbour.second);
        int neighbourN = int(neighbour.first);
        int distThroughNeighbour = neighbourW + Next.second;
        if (distThroughNeighbour < minDist[neighbourN] && !Visited[neighbourN])
        {
          // Curr.add_successor(nodes.at(neighbourN));
          minDist[neighbourN] = distThroughNeighbour;
          NextNode.add_successor(neighbourN, distThroughNeighbour); // add_successor will update a  vertex if the vertex already exists 
          Queue.push(NextNode); // not the right node to update & push ?
        }
      }
      Visited[Next.first] = 1; // too late in the execution ?
    }
    return minDist;
  }

private:
  vector<Node> nodes;
};



int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  // if ( argc != 5 || ( argv[4][0] != 'd' && argv[4][0] != 'b' ) )
  // {
  //   cerr << "[e] Please provide input file name, the source and sink nodes, and the algorithm to use." << endl;
  //   cerr << "Usage: ./hw1 <filename> <source> <sink> <d|b>" << endl;
  //   return numeric_limits<int>::min();
  // }

  ifstream fin( argv[1], ifstream::in );
  if ( !fin.is_open() )
  {
    cerr << "[e] Error opening the input file." << endl;
    return numeric_limits<int>::min();
  }

  string line, str;
  uint64_t from, to, weight;

  /* the first line contains the number of nodes (0 <= node_index <= num_nodes - 1) */
  getline( fin, line );
  Graph g( stoi( line ) );
  
  /* the remaining lines encode the edges of the graph */
  while ( getline( fin, line ) )
  {
    stringstream ss( line );

    /* the first number in each line is the "from" node */
    getline( ss, str, ' ' );
    from = stoi( str );

    /* the second number in each line is the "to" node */
    getline( ss, str, ' ' );
    to = stoi( str );

    /* the third number in each line is the weight */
    getline( ss, str, ' ' );
    weight = stoi( str );

    g.add_edge( from, to, weight );
  }
  g.dijkstra_shortest_path( 0, 5 );
  // auto const answer = argv[4][0] == 'd' ? g.dijkstra_shortest_path( atoi( argv[2] ), atoi( argv[3] ) )
  //                                       : g.bellman_ford_shortest_path( atoi( argv[2] ), atoi( argv[3] ) );

  // /* check correctness & compute length */
  // auto length = checker.check_path( answer, atoi( argv[2] ), atoi( argv[3] ) );
  
  // if ( length == numeric_limits<int>::min() )
  // {
  //   cout << "[e] Wrong answer: incorrect path." << endl;
  //   return length;
  // }
  // else if ( length == numeric_limits<int>::max() )
  // {
  //   cout << "[ans] Found that no path exists, or there is a negative weight loop." << endl;
  //   return length;
  // }

  // cout << "[ans] Found shortest path of length " << length << ": ";
  // for ( auto& n : answer )
  // {
  //   cout << n << " ";
  // }
  // cout << endl;

  // return length;
  return 0;
}
```

Input file as txt :

```
10
0 1 2
0 2 3
0 3 10
1 2 3
1 3 1
2 3 3
2 4 4
0 4 3
4 6 3
3 7 3
2 6 1
3 5 4
5 7 2
7 9 1
6 8 3
8 9 0
```

Comment: "you should be able to launch it by passing the input file name as an arg." it is unlikely that someone will do that. It is much easier for others to reproduce your issue when you put the input hardcoded in the code. (assuming the problem is not reading from file)

Comment: did you use a debugger? I didn't find any `cout` or other output, so how do you know what your code does?

Comment: yes i'm exclusively working with a debugger for now 
i could also print minDist and visited at the end.

Comment: First problem, there are 16 nodes in the data, but the first line says 10.

Comment: each line encodes an edge not a node, numbers on the first 2 columns are source - target for each edge and they go from 0 to 9